# Wondering if this code excerpt can represent a event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

Can we call this:
 `$('#nomeInput').keypress(function(){ //code here...` 
an event listener?

Thanks.

Comment: lol. No. :) I was just wondering... the main point is, is to properly understand what an event listener is. Instead, I asked this "quick like homework" question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The function you pass to the `keypress` method is an event listener.

Comment: I believe the precision calling even listener not to the all code, but to the function is passed onto keypress makes the difference to my newbie eyes...

Answer (score 1):

at least [jQuery does](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) ... so I would say YES

Comment: Well... it says: "Bind an event handler to the "keypress" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element."

Can we presume that, bind an event handler is adding a event listener?